# Passing Dig command in nmap

Tags: scripting, nmap, dig

I have an issue to take the result of the `dig` command and pass it to `nmap` command like:

```
for ip in 'dig mydomain.com -t ns +short'
do nmap $ip
done
```

Comment: Hello binharry. Please take a little more time to ask your question in a way that we've a chance of understanding it. Perhaps if you provide an example of the sort of input you've got and corresponding output you'd like we'd be able to match that. Also please show what you've tried. You can use formatting to mark out code with the `{}` command (or with backticks), for example, "using the `nmap` command"

Comment: It looks like bin harry hit the ENTER key before finishing the question. It's easy to complete it though - just hit the [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/646637/edit) link.

Comment: Do you also have a question? You say you have an issue. You don't say what is your issue, and you don't say what you expect from Stackexchange. By the way, I think the quotes around the `dig` command are not what you want. Quotes just make a string; the command is not executed.

Comment: use dig to create a list of IPs then pass it to nmap via -iL option

Answer (score 0):

Your `dig` command returns a number of lines of output.  Each line is a host name.  You want to run `nmap` on each host name.

The `xargs` utility is used to run commands with the arguments given as inputs to `xargs`:

```bsh
dig mydomain.com -t ns +short | xargs -I {} nmap {}
```

This would run `nmap` once for each line of output from `dig`.

Or, if you want to run `nmap` in parallel, two at a time, and if your `xargs` implementation supports it (I don't know if this makes sense to you, but it's possible to do),

```bsh
dig mydomain.com -t ns +short | xargs -I {} -P 2 nmap {}
```

Another approach would be to read the lines of output from `dig` in an explicit `while` loop into a shell variable, and then call `nmap` on the value of that variable:

```bsh
dig mydomain.com -t ns +short |
while IFS= read -r host; do
    nmap "$host"
done
```

A variant of this would be to collect the hostnames in an array (which would require a shell that knows about arrays), and call `nmap` on all array elements at once:

```bsh
dig mydomain.com -t ns +short |
{ readarray -t hosts; nmap "${hosts[@]}"; }
```

Or, use the positional parameters and do the same thing:

```bsh
dig mydomain.com -t ns +short |
{
    set --
    while IFS= read -r host; do
        set -- "$@" "$host"
    done
    nmap "$@"
}
```

Or, just use the `-iL` option with `nmap` and feed the hostnames in that way

```bsh
nmap -iL <( dig mydomain.com -t ns +short )
```

or, without a process substitution,

```bsh
dig mydomain.com -t ns +short | nmap -iL -
```

---

The main issue with your code is that your loop will do a single iteration with the literal string `dig mydomain.com -t ns +short` as the value of `$ip`.

You are also using `$ip` unquoted in the body of the loop, in the call to `nmap`, which means that the shell would split its value up into multiple words before calling the utility.  The `nmap` utility would get the words `dig`, `mydomain.com`, `-t`, `ns`, and `+short` as its arguments.  It would then proceed to complain about the `-t` option which it doesn't quite understand.

Now, you *could* "fix" this by changing your single quotes to backticks, which turns the single quoted string into a command substiution, but this would be quite inelegant as a general way of iterating over the ouput of a command, not least because it relies on splitting the output into words on whitespace and applying filename globbing to each word, and also because the shell needs to read *all of the output* of the command before even starting its first iteration of the loop.

All of the variations of code above are better ways of solving the issue of reading the output of some command and feeding it, line by line, into `nmap`.